# Applying body shape to a shape key

Tags: mesh, transforms, shape-keys

Okay so I'm quite new to blender I've been doing a lot currently I have a body mesh that I've been working on. Now I'm trying to copy the shape of the body mesh to another body mesh which will be used as clothing. But for some weird reason the shape keys doesn't appear to hold the actual shape of the first mesh.

And I have been watching a lot of tutorial videos The weird thing is the edits that I make to the shape keys from the original body mesh show when I transfer them over to the new onesthetic clothing so if I make say the pants but bigger in the first mesh when I apply it to the second one it actually moves the butt bigger but it doesn't change to the shape of the original mesh. It just keeps the same shape as the second one but just makes the butt bigger slightly. But the full shape of the first mesh does not transform to the second one when I use the sliders. So if I go from 0 to 1 just a slight change happens and not the full transformation that's shown in many of the tutorial videos.

Does anyone know how I can fix this or if it's just something wrong with the way I created the shape keys in the mesh file?